# How to make per-window keyboard layouts with plain XMonad?

Tags: keyboard-layout, window, xmonad

I've been using plain XMonad for some time (not combined with KDE/GNome). Currently, I'm switching between keyboard layouts simply by a key combination globally:

```
[ ((modMask , xK_Scroll_Lock ),
    spawn "setxkbmap -layout us ; xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap")
, ((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_Scroll_Lock),
    spawn "setxkbmap -layout cz ; xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap") ]
```

However that's a bit inconvenient. For many windows (i.e. browser, terminal) I need to keep the US layout most of the time. I need the localized layout only for text editors in 99% of cases. And I switch windows/workspaces a lot, so I have to switch the layouts manually almost every time I switch.

Ideally I'd like to achieve:

- By pressing the key combination I set some kind of flag for the currently focused window.
- XMonad calls the `spawn` commands automatically according to the flags when window focus changes.

How to do that (if it's possible)? Thanks for help.

(Bonus: Manage the flags externally by some kind of command from scripts.)

Answer (score 5):

Install **kbdd** daemon which does the job.

Run this at startup:

```
kbdd
setxkbmap "us,ua" -option grp:scroll_toggle
```

That's all!

To display your layout in a widget you can find this Ruby code useful:

```
  interface = 'ru.gentoo.KbddService'
  member = 'layoutChanged'
  mon = open "| dbus-monitor --monitor \"sender='#{interface}',member='#{member}'\""
  loop do
    str = mon.gets
    if str =~ /layoutChanged/
      lang = mon.gets[/.\Z/] # lang is now either 0 or 1 depending on the current layout
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [scim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Common_Input_Method) and/or [ibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus). Both daemons can be started in an `.Xsession`. From my experience, ibus is the way to go, but might not have support for your input method.

An example configuration is documented for [xfce](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/scim).

*Disclaimer: I would have added this as a comment, rather then an answer.*